# How do I maintain a template of my excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 files:

1. Excel workbook with buttons and vba code to write to another excel workbook(template)
2. A template with formatting and tables.

The first file(tool) imports data to the template. I was thinking it might be possible for the user to accidentally save the template file causing the template to be overwritten.

My goal is to keep a copy of the template with no data on it always available for the tool to use.

How do I approach this?

Comment: One idea is to keep copies of the formatting/tables template worksheets directly in file 1. You can keep these worksheets hidden so the end-user will never actually see them. When you want to create an export, you can copy these hidden sheets into a new workbook, and then populate it with the data.

Comment: With the added bonus that if you version your tool you can be sure it's using the corresponding template sheet version.

Comment: Easiest way is add lane to tool code to save that draft file as other workbook  in desktop.